# Writing data to an NFC tag that does not fit

Tags: android, tags, uri, nfc, ndef

My Android app at the moment consumes a URL for a Google spreadsheet through pasting from the clipboard, reading a QR code, or reading from NFC. I'm having trouble writing to an NFC tag and I get this error:

> [ERROR:nfa_rw_act.cc(1571)] Unable to write NDEF. Tag maxsize=137, request write size=171

I cannot write to this tag because the payload I'm trying to write it is larger than the writable space on it.

All I'm trying to do is write the URL I've already read (from clipboard or QR) to an NFC tag, and also add my app record so it launches the Play Store to my app in case the user doesn't have it installed already. Unfortunately, it seems this is too much data. I thought about maybe only including the spreadsheetID value, but I think this will add complications in the future when I inevitably want to add support for spreadsheets outside of Google Sheets.

Here's how I'm writing it currently:

```
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage() {
    String text = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit?usp=sharing";

    NdefRecord appRecord = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord(context.getPackageName());
    NdefRecord relayRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, new String("application/" + context.getPackageName()).getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")), null, text.getBytes());

    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {relayRecord, appRecord});
}
```

Is writing just the ID ("1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms" in this case) my only option? I'm also assuming the NFC tag I'm using is an average size and not a super tiny one for 2018.

EDIT:

Thanks to Michael I was able to get it to fit, though barely (134/137 bytes). I write the URI to NFC via this:

```
NdefRecord relayRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(text);
```

I added this intent filter to catch it:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="docs.google.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

And I read the NFC tag with this:

```
NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
        }

        for (NdefRecord r : messages[0].getRecords()) {
            if (r.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN) {
                byte[] payload = r.getPayload();
                try {
                    String payloadText = new String(payload, 1, payload.length - 1, "UTF-8");
                    int firstByte = payload[0];
                    return getUriPrefix(firstByte) + payloadText;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Read error";
                }
            }
        }
```

And the first byte from the URI compression I get via this, even though I only ever assign "04" (4 when I read it as int) in my app:

```
private String getUriPrefix(int firstByte) {
    if (firstByte == 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (firstByte == 1) {
        return "http://www.";
    } else if (firstByte == 2) {
        return "https://www.";
    } else if (firstByte == 3) {
        return "http://";
    } else if (firstByte == 4) {
        return "https://";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you got in the log is pretty clear. Your NDEF message is too large to fit the data area of the tag. The obvious solution would be to use NFC tags with a sufficiently large storage capacity -- there's quite a few larger tags available. There's nothing else you could do about it if you want to store exactly that NDEF message.

However, there is ways to improve the NDEF message itself. You currently use a MIME type record to store a URL. That's definitely not the best choice of a record type to store a URL. (or actually any application-specific data). The MIME type that you chose costs ("application/" + context.getPackageName()).length() = 31 bytes (assuming your package name is 19 bytes).

- If you used an NFC Forum external type record instead, you could create a much shorter type name of the form "mydomain.tld:appurl", so this would save quite a few bytes.

  ```
  relayRecord = NdefRecord.createExternal("mydomain.tld", "appurl", text.getBytes());
  ```
- Since you want to store a URL, there's even a more efficient (and readily available) record type: the NFC Forum URI well-known type. The type name of that record consists only of the single letter "U", so this would already save 30 bytes compared to your MIME type record. Moreover, the URI record type uses a compression scheme to further reduce the size of the record: there is a list of well-known URI prefixes (e.g. "https://") that can be represented as a single byte in the URI record (the method `NdefRecord.createUri()` will automatically take care of that compression). Consequently, you would save another 7 bytes.

  ```
  relayRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(text);
  ```

Comment: Would these changes still launch only my app when the NFC tag is read?

Comment: @ZeekAran Since you include the Android Application Record, yes. Not the other way round though, i.e. if you register your app for the URI record, other tags with a *matching* URI may also trigger your app.

Comment: So it seems if I try your first suggestion (replacing "mydomain.tld" with context.getPackageName()), I'm only saving 5 bytes in this case (error message says I tried to write 166, originally it said 171). Am I understanding that correctly or should I not be using context.getPackageName?

Comment: Hm. So I was able to write to the tag with option 2 (134/137 bytes, phew!), and as far as I know it works. It opens my app even if it's not in the foreground, and launches the play store if not installed. But, it's not tripping any of my if statements for not being Ndef. What is it now? Is this a standard way of writing to tags? Because I'm finding little referencing this in SO.

Comment: Regarding "replacing "mydomain.tld" with context.getPackageName())": No, you should not! You should use your domain name there, not a full package name. You can reflect the specific application in the record name component (where I used "appurl").

Comment: @ZeekAran Regarding "But, it's not tripping any of my if statements for not being Ndef.": I don't understand what you try to say with that. Could you give more details? (If necessary, in a new question.)

Comment: I'll fiddle around a bit more and if I still can't get it to work, I'll post another. Thank you so much Michael!

Comment: @ZeekAran I just reread the above; did you create an intent filter that matchrs the URI record?

Comment: I used if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) { as well as ACTION_TAG and neither were tripped reading the tag, though I think I might've just messed everything up due to my limited understanding of this area of Android.

Comment: I did not update it. It's still set to NDEF Mime type equal to my app.

Comment: @ZeekAran well, if you don't have a matching intent filter, Android won't dispatch an NFC intent.

Comment: Thank you sir, I learned a lot this last week. You can see my completed solution above. I owe most of it to you. It appears to be working perfectly in my app for now. Let me know if I have any glaring issues.

Comment: @ZeekAran regarding your solution: there is no need to manually recover the payload from the URI record. Just use the toUri() method.

Comment: However, you should test if the record type is RTD_URI.